# How to await canvas loadFromJSON in file reader

Tags: javascript, canvas, async-await, promise, fabricjs

I am trying to make html canvas.loadFromJSON async request but I could not make it work. I have an input file field which accepts json file. On input field change I open a new file reader and inside file reader's onload event I load uploaded file's json in canvas.

This is the code that detects the input field change event and loads json:

```
jsonField.value.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = async function (f) {
    var data = f.target.result;

    
    initCanvas(canvas, canWrapper);

    imgField.value.addEventListener("change", handleImageSelect);

    try{
        await loadJSONTemplate(data);

        //--- Any code here does not wait for loadJSONTemplate method to finish
    }catch (error) {
        // Handle error if loadFromJSON fails
    }

    //--- There is a code block here which should run after loadFromJSON has completed execution.
    await nextTick();

    watchingCanvasGradient.value = true;
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
});
```

And this is the function that accepts json and loads data into the canvas:

```
async function loadJSONTemplate(json) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    canvas.loadFromJSON(json, () => {
      // Have more code here to run 
      resolve();
    }, (error) => {
      reject(error);
    });
  });

}
```

Can anyone help me, what am I missing or doing wrong? Thanks.

I tried to place the loadJSONTemplate inside a try/catch but the code inside the try block is not waiting for the async function to complete execution. It should run some code after the canvas.loadFromJSON execution is complete.